# Python Killed after saving or loading numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I am trying to learn deep learning, especially how to do 'speaker diarization ([github link](https://github.com/taylorlu/Speaker-Diarization)).

I built an environment on Ubuntu to run a speaker diarization project on github.

However, I faced a 'Killed' message during generating embeddings for speaker.
[image: After I ran 'dmesg -e']

I could find that error had occurred with below code (From [here](https://github.com/taylorlu/Speaker-Diarization/blob/master/ghostvlad/generate_embeddings.py))

```
np.savez('training_data', train_sequence=train_sequence, train_cluster_id=train_cluster_id)
```

After I reduce the epochs, I found that training_data.npz is about 500MB (much smaller than my RAM) and somehow generating embeddings is normally finished with few epochs.

But after this, I faced same error on loading this small training_data.npz for training.

```
train_data = np.load('./ghostvlad/training_data.npz')
```

To summarize, I don't understand why my system can't save or load this small file.

(P.S. Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: `.npz` files are compressed. There's no telling how much memory the dataset will consume once decompressed.

Comment: @AKX So, it could be much more bigger, right?

Comment: That's what I mean, yes.

Comment: @AKX I got it. Thanks.